# IN(SELECT .....) MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I do not speak English.
I use google translator.

```
(`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,)
(`members` text NOT NULL)
```

I have the following query:

```
SELECT members FROM team WHERE id = 37
```

the result is: `25,36,38,87` work perfectly

and I have this other query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE id_users IN ( 25,36,38,87 )
```

work perfectly

but this does not work

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE id_users IN (SELECT members FROM team WHERE id = 37  )
```

I have to fix it with PHP :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id_users IN ( $members )
```

thank you very much everyone. and again, sorry for my english. I use google translator. Very good site

**Added** schema from comment:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS team ( 
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    members text NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users ( 
    id_users int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    name varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_usuario) 
)
```

Comment: What are the attributes for each table? If you used 'id' instead of 'id_users', would that work?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `team` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `members` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)




CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id_users` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_usuario`)
)

Answer (score 1):

You should fix your schema to use an association table instead of a CSV column.

In the mean time, you can use [`find_in_set`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), something like this should work:

```
select u.*
from users u
join team t on find_in_set(u.id, t.members)
where t.id = 37
```

But you really should fix your schema, a CSV column is certainly an SQL anti-pattern and causes nothing but trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think your `id_users` may be in different type from `members` in `team`.
`members` is in text, but not int.

Comment: forgiveness for my English.
I do not speak English.
if I do not understand.

Comment: Normally, I use `Split(...)` in VB to make the text `members` into an array. I do not know how to split it directly in SQL. Sorry.

Comment: Oh, I think you can try to make the result of `SELECT` into your new SQL query. I mean, firstly, you can use `SELECT members FROM team WHERE id = 37` to get the members. And then, you can directly make it into your second query. Such as, "SELECT *  FROM users WHERE id_users IN ( " & members & " ) ".

Answer (score 0):

members is a text field, and id_users is an int. They are different types

Comment: members is text
  because it has a comma (,) between the numbers

Comment: Member is a text field. If you use IN, you must provide a set, not a text field. Just because it displays with commas does not mean that it will be treated as a set. So, for your example, if members was "12,13,14", the query would be: id_users in "12,13,14"

Comment: I have to fix it with PHP

    SELECT * 
      FROM users 
            WHERE id_users IN ( $members  ) 


thank you very much everyone.
and again, sorry for my english.
I use google translator.
Very good site